# route to specific action using urlManager in yii 1

Tags: php, regex, yii

i have an issue here,i'm trying to route "http://example.com/xxx/xxx/index.php/Offer/Dashboard" to this action "http://example.com/xxx/xxx/index.php/marketing/Offer/Dashboard"

notice : marketing is a module in my application.

how can i do it using urlManager in yii 1

Comment: do you need all routes to be redirected into marketing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible `rule` in `urlManager`:

```
'<controller:Offer>/<action:Dashboard>' => 'marketing/<controller>/<action>'
```

More on [URL Management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)